# LINQ on IList of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Ilist of objects

```
IList list = new List<object[]>();
```

I want to identify in the list of object which element has `object["name"]="No Name"` and `object["lastName"]="No Name"`.

I've tried so:

```
var myElem= from x in list
    where x.Field<string>("NAME")=="No Name"
    select x.toList();
```

And I'm getting:

> "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Collections.IList'.  'Where' not found."

Please advise

Answer (score 3):

You have a list of object arrays. object arrays have no string accessor, so `object["name"]="No Name"` makes no sense. You can only access with an ordinal: `x[0] == "No Name"`, or try `Any`

Also create your original list as generic to alleviate the initial error.

```
IList<object[]> list = new List<object[]>();

var myElem = from x in list
    where x.Any(y => y.ToString() == "No Name")
    select x.toList();
```

Comment: `==` operator on `object` and `string`? The compiler doesn't like that.

Comment: Looks like the compiler is written by Tim Schmelter

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that LINQ is not supported on raw collections, only on generic ones. Therefore, you need to make your list generic like this:

```
var myElem = from x in list.Cast<object[]>
    where // some condition
    select x.toList();
```

The `Cast<object[]>` will cause the `list`  to be treated as an `IEnumerable<object[]>`, hence make it a generic enumerable and allow the LINQ expressions.

Now, back to your code, the object["name"] seems an illegal expression in C#, as object does not support such access. In in case the `list` is really an object array retrieved from some data source, then the `"name"` and `"lastName"` items will just be an array elements. If that is so, refer to to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514774/linq-on-ilist-of-objects/20514884#20514884) of fellow user jenson-button-event.

In case you have a list of data rows or some indexeable structure, then you should use that structure's type instead of `object[]`.  For instance, if you are using a `DataRow`, the code should look like this:

```
IList list = new List<DataRow>();
var myElem = from x in list.Cast<DataRow>
    where x["name"] == "No Name" || x["lastName"] == "No Name"
    select x.toList();
```

Or even better (to avoid raw collections):

```
IList<DataRow> list = new List<DataRow>();
var myElem = from x in list
    where x["name"] == "No Name" || x["lastName"] == "No Name"
    select x.toList();
```

Comment: @Grundy, `IList` is not a _generic_ enumerable. Linq is enabled on generic enumerable instances only.

Comment: @IvayloSlavov yep, you right, did not pay attention that assign to `IList` as interface and not generic